# git stash restores ignored files

Tags: git, gitignore, git-stash

I committed in the past some wrong files to git. After that I excluded and ignored these files:

```
git rm --cached -r config.php
git reset config.php
echo "config.php" >> .gitignore
git update-index --assume-unchanged config.php
```

Now git commit works great. Changes in config.php are not committed.

But: If I stash the working directory for example to switch the branch, than config.php is restored from the local repos.

How can I use `git stash` without changing ignored (and from index excluded) files?

Comment: did you commit your .gitignore after you added config.php to it?

Comment: Yes, .gitignore is committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config.php' \
--prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

May be a `reset` is necessary to exclude it from future commits:

```
git reset config.php
```

After all information of config.php are removed from local branches, I made a forced push to update remote repos:

```
git push origin master --force
```

Now, my stash area works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Answer**

You did a `git rm --cached -r config.php`, but didn't commit that change.

Next you did `git reset config.php`, which cleared the effect of `git rm` you had done previously. So you are right now back to where you started from.

Then, you added `config.php` to `.gitignore`. That won't have any affect since the `config.php` is still tracked right now.

Finally, you did a `git update-index --assume-unchanged config.php` due to which any changes are not visible locally if you do a `git status` / `git diff`. These steps give the illusion that `git rm` and `.gitignore` worked fine when they didn't.

Instead, do this (the `-r` flag was redundant, this is not a directory)

```
git rm --cached config.php
echo config.php >> .gitignore && git add .gitignore
git commit -m "removing config.php"
```

**Original Answer**

> But: If I stash the working directory for example to switch the branch, than config.php is restored from the local repos.

Well, You just removed config.php from the current branch ( lets call it `master`), but the  another branch `other` is still tracking it. So that's why you see it. Its got nothing to do with `git stash`.

You should probably merge the branch `master` into `other` to bring the commit into the branch `other`.

Comment: I don't think so: `git status` on the second branch doesn't list the changed file. Also the second branch was created after ignoring the file.